# issue - How to avoid showing login page if already logged with asp net core Identityserver4?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

How to prevent an authenticated user from being not able to open the IndentitySever login page so that they do not re-enter their credentials since they are already logged in

I am using two separate applications Blazor Web Assembly  hosted on Asp net and WebApi that uses Identity Server for Authentication.

The browser opens to the login page, I enter the credentials and the server application of identityServer completes the process successfully and redirects me to the home page, then I pressed the back button of the browser and the identityServer login page opens

I even tried to activate the remember me to make identity remember that the user logged in but I still get the same result the login page opens although user is authenticated

Code App with IdentityServer4
Startup.cs

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();
            //.AddSigningCredential(;
        services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddIdentityServerJwt();
        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
            /*ptions.SlidingExpiration = true;*/
        });
```

Code App with IdentityServer4
Login.cshtml

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
            // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
            }
            if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
            {
                return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = Input.RememberMe });
            }
            if (result.IsLockedOut)
            {
                _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
                return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                return Page();
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return Page();
    }
```

Any thoughts will be greatly appreciated.
Best

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question directly, you could check if a `idsrv.session` cookie is present

```
this.Request.Cookies["idsrv.session"]
```

As an alternative, you could let your user log in again if they want to. Let's take a look at the IdentityServer4 demo:
https://demo.identityserver.io/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fdiagnostics

Log in using:

```
User: bob 
Password: bob
```

Now click back and take a look at the header, you can see that you are indeed logged in.

Now let's enter some new credentials:

```
User: alice
Password: alice
```

And now see what happens

Comment: Problem is, if bob previously logged in into client apps, his session ID gets discareded/lost, so it's not possible to sing him out of all apps any longer.